# View UrlGatewayLogin didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-urls

It's a bit repetitive this error is everywhere to find, but I'm a bit confused about what is happening.

I'm trying to pass a token in the url for the user to login like so `http://localhost:8000/auth/login/?token=token`. After the user is authenticated it should be redirected to `dashboard`. But I'm getting [this error](http://dpaste.com/04Z1X8D). Can you help me understand what is happening?

View:

```
import logging

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings

from business_accounts.models.my_user import MyUser


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

jwt_decode_handler = api_settings.JWT_DECODE_HANDLER

class UrlGatewayLogin(View):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        page_group = kwargs.get('page_group')

        token = request.GET.get('token')

        try:
            payload = jwt_decode_handler(token)
            user = MyUser.objects.get(pk=payload.get('id'))
            user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        authenticate(token=token)
        logger.warning("User is=%s", user)
        print(user)
        login(request, user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard', {'page_group': page_group})
```

URL:

```
url(r'^auth/login/$', UrlGatewayLogin.as_view(), name='auth-login')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, your view should *always* return an `HttpResponse` object. At the moment, you have `return None` in your `except block`.

You could prevent the error by doing something like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest
try:
    ...
except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest("Invalid token")
```

Comment: ok that is good, now I'm getting Invalid Token error, so I need a bit more handling to have here, is this even possible to achieve?

Comment: That's a separate issue, I can't help you with that. Note that you are not checking the result of `authenticate(token=token)`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up, I'll check to see what am I getting there